# TypeError when using validate_email package in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, validation, email

I keep getting this error when using:

```
d = {'email': ['first@second.com', 'third@fourth.com']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1 = df[df['email'].apply(validate_email)]
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - Any idea where this could come from. "email" is of dtype object

Thanks Manuel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It looks like you're really close (good for you) but your example is not **complete**.  Please include `imports` statements and show exactly what `df` is.  Perhaps it's implicit when using Pandas (which I don't know), but in general, undefined variables should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error message, it looks like you're importing `validate_email` incorrectly. Try replacing your import with:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
```

Comment: Or use `apply(validate_email.validate_email)`, if I understand the answer correctly.

Comment: You were right, I found out that I imported a totally different package, validate-email-address instead of validate_email. Thanks a lot for your help.